# Exclusion of admin.logenty from dumpdata

Tags: python, django

I am trying to dump my data using

```
python manage.py dumpdata --exclude=admin.logentry
```

but it still gets included in the final json. Any hint what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Who did you export/create the ***file***?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Drop the `=`. It's `--exclude admin.logentry`.

Comment: [Documenation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/django-admin/#dumpdata) for reference.